# Jquery datetime picker has to open only when clicked on Calendar image

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I am using Jquery datetimepicker. I don't want to open the calendar on tabbing to the text box. I want to place a calendar image at the end of the text box. When I click once on the calendar image, I want to open the calendar to select date-time. This option is working. If I use only date picker control - where I can select only dates - it is not working.

In the following code Datepicker works exactly the way as I want, without time option. I wnat the date and time option and it has to open only once, when I click on image.

DatePicker:

```
 $("#ImageDate").datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      showOn: 'button',
      buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif"
});
```

Datetimepicker:

```
$("#ImageDate1").datetimepicker({
       autoOpen: false,
       showOn: 'button',
       buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
       buttonImageOnly: true,
       format: 'm/d/Y H:i',
});
```

Comment: Provide your code so we can check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Need To Trigger Date Picker On Click Of That Image 
Here is example Which May Help You....

**Js Code:**

```
$(function() {
  $('#startTime1Trigger').on('click', function(){
    var $t = $(this),
        $tp = $(this).parent().siblings('.timepicker').first();

    if ($tp.timepicker())
      $('#startTime1').timepicker('show');
  });
});
```

**Html Code:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.10.0/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.10.0/jquery.timepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<label for="startTime1">* Proposed Start Time:</label>
<div class="input-group">
  <input class="timeinput form-control timepicker timepicker-with-dropdown text-center" id="startTime1" name="startTime1" placeholder="Start Time 1">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-down fa-fw" id="startTime1Trigger" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Its showing only time part, i want date time and also on focus on text box it should not open popup. Popup should come only when i click on the image button. I want textbox should be editable so that users can enter manually also.